# using javascript for changing dynamically created ASP.NET image control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've created a table in my ASP.NET (C#,VS2010) web app whose rows and cells should be created dynamically (read from DB), I have an image in each row which is being created dynamically (in codebehind file), how can I change its image (display a hover) with mouse over? it is easy using a small JavaScript function for statically created controls, but how can it be done for dynamically created controls? can I use inline JS functions? how should I implement it?

thanks

Comment: use CSS. Don't abuse JavaScript

Comment: how can I do it with CSS? can you give me a tip please?

Comment: `img:hover { background-image: 'other.png' }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the images you create dynamically a class, using their [`CssClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property:

```
// Dynamically create the image control in code behind
Image image = new Image();
Image.CssClass = "change-on-hover";
Image.ImageUrl = "image.jpg"; // Of course, this is dynamic from the database

// Save the alternative image URL in a data-attribute
Image.Attributes["data-alternate-image"] = "image-over.jpg";

parent.Controls.Add(image);
```

This will render each image like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="change-on-hover" 
  data-alternative-image="image-over.jpg" />
```

Then in jQuery, you can find all the images with this class to bind the behavior:

```
$("img.change-on-hover")
  .on("mouseover", function(e) {
    // Save original src (image.jpg)
    $(this).data("original-image") = this.src;

    // Change src to alternative (image-over.jpg)
    this.src = $(this).data("data-alternate-image");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(e) {
    // Change src back to original
    this.src = $(this).data("original-image");
  });
```

The `data-alternative-image` attribute is a nice way to store some information inside the image tag from code behind, that you can then later read in your JavaScript event handler. You can make your own data-attributes any way you like.

Some more info about the data-attribute: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/